# Efficient searching according to "starts with"

Tags: java, algorithm, loops, search

I facing some issue with write logic for below problem.

I have two ArrayLists of strings:

- List1: contains 5 million strings
- List2: will create on users input and contains some strings/characters(Ex. a,b,c,g,l,pd,sp,mta)

Now I have to split list1 into multiple Lists according to startsWith strings in list2 like in above case. I need to create 8 lists as starts with '**a**', '**b**','**c**', '**g**', '**l**','**pd**', '**sp**' and '**mta**'

But the condition for above is I have to iterate List1 or List2 only once. i.e. worst complexity for algorithm should be size of List1 (5 million).

It is allowed to use collections.sort() method

Code I have tried

```
    // Create List for search strings.
    List<String> CharList = new ArrayList<String>();
    CharList.add("a");
    CharList.add("b");
    CharList.add("e");
    CharList.add("z");
    CharList.add("4");
    CharList.add("1");
    CharList.add("zi");

    List<String> recordList = new ArrayList<String>();

    // Creating dummy data with 100 character in live environment it can be
    // around 50 lakhs strings
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        char[] chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCGDKL0123456789".toCharArray();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        Random random = new Random();
        for (int i1 = 0; i1 < 6; i1++) {
            char c = chars[random.nextInt(chars.length)];
            sb.append(c);
        }
        String output = sb.toString();
        recordList.add(output);
    }

    // Adding some data mannually
    recordList.add("zink");
    recordList.add("zebra");
    recordList.add("zzzzzz");
    Collections.sort(CharList, String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
    Collections.sort(recordList, String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);

    System.out.println("RECORDLIST ===>" + recordList);
    System.out.println("***************************************************");
    System.out.println("Charlist ===>" + CharList);
    System.out.println("***************************************************");

    List<List> lists = new ArrayList<List>();

    int startIndex = 0, charPointer = 0;
    while (startIndex < recordList.size() && charPointer < CharList.size()) {
        List<String> temp = new ArrayList<String>();

        boolean isHit = false;
        String currentRecord = recordList.get(startIndex);
        String partitionSattement = CharList.get(charPointer);
        while (currentRecord.startsWith(partitionSattement.toUpperCase())
                || currentRecord.startsWith(partitionSattement.toLowerCase())) {
            temp.add(recordList.get(startIndex));
            isHit = true;
            startIndex++;
        }
        if (!isHit) {
            startIndex++;
        }
        if (!temp.isEmpty()) {
            lists.add(temp);
            System.out.println(CharList.get(charPointer) + "====>" + temp);
        }
        charPointer++;
    }
```

Comment: where is Your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just using the `String` `startsWith` method won't work in this case. Consider what happens if the first pattern does not match any input - you'll loop through all strings in the input list without finding a match, even though subsequent pattern matches do exist.

What we need to do instead is compare each pattern against the initial characters of each input string and process accordingly. Let's say we have an input string `str` and a pattern `pat`. Let `subStr` be the first `pat.length()` characters of `str`. Now we can compare `subStr` and `pat` using the `String` `compareToIgnoreCase` method. There are three cases to consider:

`subStr < pat` Move to the next input string.

`subStr == pat` Add `str` to output for `pat` and move to the next input string.

`subStr > pat` Move to the next pattern.

Here's some code to illustrate (I've kept your variable names where possible).

```
List<List<String>> output = new ArrayList<>();
for(int i=0; i<CharList.size(); i++) output.add(new ArrayList<String>());

int startIndex=0;
int charPointer=0;              
while(startIndex < recordList.size() && charPointer < CharList.size())
{
    String charStr = CharList.get(charPointer);
    String recStr = recordList.get(startIndex);

    int cmp;
    if(recStr.length() < charStr.length()) 
    {
        cmp = -1;
    }
    else
    {
        String recSubStr = recStr.substring(0, charStr.length());           
        cmp = recSubStr.compareToIgnoreCase(charStr);           
    }

    if(cmp <= 0)
    {
        if(cmp == 0) output.get(charPointer).add(recStr);
        startIndex++;
    }
    else 
    {
        charPointer++;
    }
}

for(int i=0; i<CharList.size(); i++)
{
    System.out.println(CharList.get(i) + " : " + output.get(i));
}
```

Also, you should note that when you include a pattern that itself starts with another pattern (e.g. `"zi"` and `"z"`) the longer pattern will never be matched, since the shorter one will capture all inputs.

Answer (score 0):

I can see two problems in your code:

1. You should remove the following segment:

   ```
   if (!isHit) {
       startIndex++;
   }
   ```

   Actually you don't need that isHit variable at all. If a string doesn't match with a pattern then you still have to compare it with the next pattern.
2. You should sort the arrays in descending order. As SirRaffleBuffle noted in the other answer you should compare the strings with the longer pattern first. Sorting the strings and patterns in descending order will automatically solve this problem.